# Publish to friends wall doesn't work with specified access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publish

We have an application that allows to users publish content to their friends wall.
It uses the user's access_token given our application.

It works stable usually, but for some reason for one of our clients it doesn't work at all.
We've checked permissions several times, removed-added them again, but still no result.
There is no error message or something, everything looks fine, complete the action, but no posts published in fact. And it doesn't work only for one person.

What possibly can be a problem?

**Updated:** The problem is actually in this OAuthException:

> Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored
>   session. This may be because the user changed the password since the
>   time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for
>   security reasons.

We tried to get access token one more time, but that didn't help. Somebody familiar with this issue?

Comment: be aware that the friend who's wall you are trying to write on is bound by that friends privacy settings.  If that friend does not allow anyone to write on their wall then the call will fail.  Does this client get any informative errors or messages when the call fails?

Comment: User owning access_token able to post on friend wall using facebook? Some users may restrict what posted in their feed. Any chance posting user blocked application from his feed?

Comment: No errors or messages. It behaves like everything is fine. And client actually can post on friend's wall directly from facebook, so it's not forbidden for him to post there.

Comment: What is the response code being returned from the post action?

Comment: None. But the function works via batch operations.

Answer (score 0):

your user might forbid people/applications to post on his wall.

Comment: Nope. I explain myself a little more. I've tryed to publish posts to several friends of client, and it didn't post it. I'm sure that they all don't forbid posting for people/applications. Can be this something else?

Answer (score 0):

"*There is no error message or something, everything looks fine, complete the action, but no posts published in fact.*"

Are you sure about this?  You should be getting back a unique stream id of the feed item just posted.

Comment: Yes. There is no item id, maybe because it's a batch operation.

Comment: How are you batching a graph post???  This is new to me and I'd love to know how you are doing it.

Comment: [Pos on facebook's blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/480/) Also you can create an array with each element in it contains request: path, method, attachments. And then run the json_encode() on it and assign to 'batch' parameter when calling method.

Comment: You should get something like this:  [
    { “code”: 200, 
      “headers”:[
          { “name”: ”Content-Type”, 
            “value”: ”text/javascript; charset=UTF-8” },
       { “name”:”ETag”, 
         “value”: ”…”
  }
      ],
      “body”: ”{\”id\”:\”…\”}”},
    { “code”: 200,
      “headers”:[
          { “name”:”Content-Type”, 
            “value”:”text/javascript; charset=UTF-8”},
          { “name”:”ETag”, 
            “value”: ”…”
       }
      ],
      “body”:”{\”data\”: [{…}]}}
]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook frequently changes its policies that sucks! 
Now, you need permission to access the wall.
You need to check if the user has permission to access your application / wall page. if user hasn't got permission then you need to ask for permission before message is streamed. Yes, that's true, it won't display any error message, unless you manually debug this to see where it is stopping.

My suggestion is:
1. use FB.login method to verify, if the user is not logged in then he should login 
2. verify the user permission for the wall page
   FB.api('/id', function(response){}); 
3. publish / stream the comments on wall 
   FB.api("/id/feed", 'post', { ... blah blah blah !

edits: 
At FB.login method, you should ask for permisions
e.g. FB.login(function(response) {..} ... ,{scope: 'offline_access,publish_stream'});

Comment: Do you mean the "publish_stream" permission? We had it. But I 've actually found  the problem, but unfortunately didn't find the solution. Look at the updated post.